# How to access a ViewportTexture's depth data as an image?

Tags: godot, image, viewport, depth

I make use of ViewportTextures, kind of like rendering security cameras on screens. Now, I'd need to access the depth textures to do some comparison of images / pixels. How do I access the depth data as an image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly, there is no built in to do this at the time of writing. Instead this is what exists:

- A bug report: [Getting depth texture from viewports](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/23847).
- A proposal: [Accessing different viewport buffers through ViewportTextures](https://github.com/godotengine/godot-proposals/issues/798). *Feel free to upvote it, and comment why you need it in your project.*
- And a pull request to add this feature: [Add access to the viewport's G-buffers (and depth).](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/pull/38926) *You can read there why it hasn't been merged. And feel free to upvote it.*

Today, the workaround is to use yet another `Viewport`, that would output the depth information (which requires a shader that reads the depth and outputs it as color), so that you get it as a regular `ViewportTexture`. See [Advanced post-processing](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/shading/advanced_postprocessing.html). *And yes, that means overhead.*